# How the files in Windows 7's HD looks like duplicated, even when accessed via Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, filesystems, file-management

I have my "Downloads" folder in Windows 7, and I have dual boot with Ubuntu. So I mounted the Windows 7's partition of the HD to copy the files from my "Downloads" folder, and I discovered that there are two "Downloads" folder with the same files, but differend locations.

When I check a file properties, one says `Location: /media/OS/Users/Wellington/Downloads`, and the other says `Location: /media/OS/Documents and Settings/Wellington/Downloads`. **But** if I delete one file, the other will be deleted too.

I thought Windows could have the files duplicated, and delete both, but I'm in Ubuntu now. And one folder is not a link to the other (at least, Nautilus - Ubuntu's file manager - is not recognizing it as a link, the icon is not of a link, and the Location information in the file's properties are showing different locations).

So, is there an explanation for that? Who is linking who? Or why this behaviour (I delete one file, and the other gets deleted)?

(not really a problem, just a curiosity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#NTFS_Junction_points) on the NTFS filesystem.  Basically you can think of it as a link.  Linux tools will not see it as a link.  Here is a [tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/ntfs_links_view.html) you can run under windows to display junctions/links.

The `\Documents and Settings` to `\Users` junction is present on Windows Vista, 7, 2008, and 2008R2 to make badly designed applications continue to with the renamed folder.